# Flask Login and Dash: weird random redirection on production

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I have a Flask app integrating a Dash application.
My Flask application use Flask-Login to handle login, which is working well.
However I have a bug in my Dash application that only happens in production: my dash application shows files (images) located in a data folder. It needs serving file at URL such as  `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/person1/person1_image.jpg` or whatever the root URL is.
So what I did is I created a route for this such as:

```py
@bp.route("/data/<path:filename>")
@login_required
def data_folder(filename):
    """Serve files located in person subfolder inside folder"""
    return send_from_directory(current_app.config["DATA_FOLDER"], filename)
```

Which works "well" in local developpement. The first time I open the page the image don't show, but when I refresh it does.
But in production, no matter how many time I refresh the page the image doesn't show.
When I check the network tab of Firefox I get this:
`302 https://my_domain.com/data/person1/person1_image.jpg`
`200 https://my_domain.com/login?next=/data/person1/person1_image.jpg`

So it appears that when trying to fetch the ressource, it redirect me to the login page, while I'm already logged in ! (As the initial page is also login-protected and I am acessing it.)
Could this be a cookie thing ? In my `config.py` I have this:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = "True"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you still having an issue with this? Can you confirm the auth/login aspect of your website is working as expected before moving on to the data_folder functionality.

Comment: Hello, yes I still do have this issue.
I feel like my login aspect is supposed to be working as it is correctly working to access the initial page. If user can access the page that request the data_folder func, then it means that it is working